# Locate string value in one column and replace value of separate column Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I have the following DF:

```
      A           B 
0     Success     1.5  
1     Duplicate   1.8  
2     NaN         1.5  
3     Rejected    23 
4     Success     12
```

I'm looking to replace column B to have the value 0 when column A is NOT 'Success'

The end result should be:

```
      A           B 
0     Success     1.5  
1     Duplicate   0  
2     NaN         0 
3     Rejected    0 
4     Success     12
```

What I have tried:

```
df.loc[
        df["A"].eq("Success") & df["A"].isnull(),
        "B",
    ] = "0"
```

I don't necessarily need to go with the above method as I am not sure its the right way to go.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `df.loc[df['A'].ne('Success'),'B']=0`.

Comment: `import numpy as np
df['B']=np.where(df.A.ne('Success'),0,df.B)
df`

Comment: Thank you, the first answer worked as I needed. I really appreciate the help.